# Brother iPrint&Scan generating "problem connecting to server 127.0.0.1"

Tags: macos, network, printing

I've been using Brother's iPrint&Scan app on my MacBookPro to scan images from a Brother multifunction printer for several years.

My MacBook recently needed minor service, and AppleCare basically completely replaced the guts, including (of course) the SSD. So I had to restore my data from backup, ***AND*** I was forced to "upgrade" to the current OS. Prior to service, I had been running the latest version of Big Sur, I think. I'm now using the latest version of Ventura (13.4).

Ever since that upgrade, whenever I start iPrint&Scan, and whenever I run a scan job, I get a bunch of "There was a problem connecting to the server “127.0.0.1”" error dialogs. I have to keep clicking the dialog's OK button or pressing the Enter key to dismiss them.

I've tried pinging Brother about this, but it's been a couple of weeks, and they haven't bothered to respond. Any suggestions of things to try or places to look? The iPrint&Scan app does its job after I've dismissed all these bogus errors -- but it's pretty annoying that I have to babysit these error dialog windows. I have no idea why iPrint&Scan is trying to use the loopback IPv4 address.

Also: It shouldn't make any difference, but this printer is connected via ethernet cable (not WiFi), and is on a reserved IP address.

Comment: The error you’re getting means that the software is looking for some “service” running locally on your machine (aka loopback or localhost) and it’s not responding. Ethernet or WiFi is irrelevant here because this is all self contained.  You’ll likely have to do a printer software reinstall to get it working